# How to remove default action(BlockApp) in android wear notification?

Tags: android, android-wear-notification

I am working on Android wear notification. I am able to add action. Everything works fine. But I wanted to avoid the default action(Block app) which you find it as the last action item in all android wear notification in the notification.

How do I remove the default action?

Comment: ..how to show the action buttons ?I have done everything as said in the sample project but my action buttons are not visible.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that. They introduced the feature on Android 5.0.1 and it's embedded into the notification mechanism.

As per wear-user experience, it should be there to grant the user a grade of control on the applications those try to push content to the Context Stream. Imagine a scenario where an application continues to spam the stream; the user would definitely appreciate the possibility to prevent it.